# Java EE App Design

Tags: spring, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, scalability, volume

I am writing a Java EE application which is supposed to consume SAP BAPIs/RFC using JCo and expose them as web-services to other downstream systems. The application needs to scale to huge volumes in scale of tens of thousands and thousands of simultaneous users.

I would like to have suggestions on how to design this application so that it can meet the required volume.

Comment: I am not using the in-built SAP's expose BAPI/RFC as web-service feature due to some custom translations required in the response.

Comment: Most important - can your SAP infrastructure itself can handle the load?

Comment: lets assume that the SAP infrastructure will be scaled to handle to load...

Answer (score 0):

Its good that you are thinking of scalability right from the design phase. Martin Abbott and Michael Fisher (PayPal/eBay fame) layout a framework called AKF Scale for scaling web apps. The main principle is to scale your app in 3 axis.

1. X-axis: Cloning of services/ data such that work can be easily distributed across instances. For a web app, this implies ability to add more web servers (clustering).
2. Y-axis: separation of work responsibility, action or data. So for example in your case, you could have different API calls on different servers.
3. Z-Axis: separation of work by customer or requester. In your case you could say, requesters from region 1 will access Server 1, requesters from region 2 will access Server 2, etc.

Design your system so that you can follow all 3 above if you need to. But when you initially deploy, you may not need to use all three methods.

You can checkout the book "The Art of Scalability" by the above authors. http://amzn.to/oSQGHb

Answer (score 0):

A final answer is not possible, but based on the information you provided this does not seem to be a problem as long as your application is stateless so that it only forwards requests to SAP and returns the responses. In this case it does not maintain any state at all. If it comes to e.g. asynchronous message handling, temporary database storage or session state management it becomes more complex. If this is true and there is no need to maintain state you can easily scale-out your application to dozens of application servers without changing your application architecture.

In my experience this is not necessarily the case when it comes to SAP integration, think of a shopping cart you want to fill based on products available in SAP. You may want to maintain this cart in your application and only submit the final cart to SAP. Otherwise you end up building an e-commerce application inside your backend.

Most important is that you reduce CPU utilization in your application to avoid a 'too-large' cluster and to reduce all kinds of I/O wherever possible, e.g. small SOAP messages to reduce network I/O.

Furthermore, I recommend to design a proper abstraction layer on top of JCo including the JCO.PoolManager for connection pooling. You may also need a well-thought-out authorization concept if you work with a connection pool managed by only one technical user.

Just some (not well structured) thoughts...